# A problem on group rings from Isaacs Algebra, a Graduate Course

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, group-rings

Updated below, but still not sure of my approach. I am trying to solve problem $13.6$ from Isaacs' *Algebra, a Graduate Course*. I am probably not understanding the question, but here is my attempt. A proper solution would be most appreciated. I copied the problem to an image for reference.

> $\textbf{13.6}$ Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $F$ a field of characteristic $p$. Construct the group algebra $A=FG$. Show that $J(A)$ has codimension one in $A$. (In other words, $\dim(J(A))=|G|-1$.)
>
> **HINT:** Work by induction on $|G|$. If $|G|>1$, let $Z\subseteq\mathbf{Z}(G)$ with $|Z|=p$, and let $1\ne z\in Z$. Show that $A/(1-z)A\cong F(G/Z)$ and that $(1-z)A\subseteq J(A)$.
>
> **NOTE:** The augmentation ideal of $A$ (see the note following Problem $12.8$) has codimension one and so is a maximal right ideal and thus contains (and therefore equals) $J(A)$. Therefore $1-g\in J(A)$ for all $g\in G$. Observe that

Using the hint I use induction starting with the fact that dimension of $ J(F(G/Z)) = |G|/p-1$

I want to show that the dimension of $J(A)=J(F(G))$ is $|G|-1$

The surjective homomorphism $\theta:F(G)\rightarrow F(G/Z)$ given by $$\sum a_g\cdot g \rightarrow \sum a_g \cdot Zg $$

then provides (Corrollary 13.2) that $J(F(G/Z)) = \theta (J(F(G)))$

Since the kernel of $\theta$ is $(1-z)A$ I know that $F(G/Z) \cong A/(1-z)A$ and that $\theta (J(A)) =J(F(G/Z)))$ so $J(F(G/Z)))=J(A)/(1-z)A$

Assuming this much is correct (I am very new at this) it seems that I need to determine the dimension of the ideal $(1-z)A$. Then I get the dimension of $J(A)$ from the equation (which I need confirmation of) $\dim(X/Y)=\dim(X)-\dim(Y)$.

I am not seeing easily what this dimension is. I think a spanning set is the set $\{1-z)g\}$ but I'm not sure how to determine the number of independent elements present. I do know (or believe) that the set of elements of $G$ is a spanning set, with the proviso that the sum of the coefficients is zero. So an unrestricted spanning set (basis) would be the set $\{1-g\}$. But this doesn't seem to get me where I am supposed to be. I also think that the elements of $(1-z)A$ are nilpotent, and thus $(1-z)A \subset J(A)$. This does seem to imply that the dimension of $J(A)$ equals $|G|-1$. But I don't think this requires the induction proof.

UPDATE: I see that the kernel is bigger than $(1-z)A$, containing $(1-y)A$ for all $1 \neq y \in Z$. However, I am still not set up to calculate the requested dimensions. My approach is obviously clumsy.

Thank you in advance for clarifying. I am trying to learn from the book.

Comment: Please don't rely on images of text. They're hard to search for and some devices do not render them.

Comment: @Shaun I fixed it.

Comment: You're already done if you can show the hint. The image $\theta(J(A))$ is codimension 1, so $\theta^{-1}\theta(J(A))=J(A)\ker\theta=J(A)$ is codimension 1.

Comment: To prove $(1-z)A\subset J(A)$, use what you know about $z$: it's central and has order $p$.

Comment: Thanks to all for the assistance. @SteveD I am not facile with the codimension argument. Why is the inverse image under $\theta$ also of codimension 1? This is probably a lame question, and I apologize. Happy to get a reference to clear up my ignorance. Gary

Comment: Look at the fourth isomorphism theorem (correspondence theorem) in the book you're reading, and note a codimension 1 subspace is a maximal subgroup of the vector space in question.

Comment: I believe I understand now. I learned a lot from this problem and the assistance I received. Many thanks, especially @SteveD. I realize codimension is not all that hard a concept, just not one I've used much, at least explicitly by name. I think the key to the problem, once terminology is understood, is to find the kernel of $\theta$ and show it is containing in $J(A)$. I got that (since 1-z is nilpotent in the present problem) but the subsequent conclusion needed your help. Routine is only routine with experience! I am less inexperienced now! Thanks and have a great day.